# Can I modify a Map through Keyset

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to apply a filter to a Map. The intention is to keep only those keys which are part of a set. The following implementation does provide the required results but I want to know if this is the right way?

```
private void filterProperties(Map<String, Serializable> properties, Set<String> filterSet) {
    Set<String> keys = properties.keySet();
    keys.retainAll(filterSet);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes!

> The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa

(see: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet())

Answer (score 2):

[Itay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781083/can-i-modify-a-map-through-keyset/5781113#5781113) is correct, however you should make sure that `properties` is not modified by other threads, or is itself a thread-safe `Map` implementation.

If `Map` is not thread-safe (e.g. HashMap) and is modified by other thread you may get `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Answer (score 0):

your code looks good. You can write a single line as   `properties.keySet().retainAll(filterSet);`

One problem I see is that the map could be un-modifiable. If that's a possibility then maybe building a new map with original entry set and then filtering and returning it will be a better option.